# Clojure module dependencies

Tags: clojure, dependency-management, modularity

I'm trying to create a modular application in clojure.

Lets suppose that we have a blog engine, which consists of two modules, for example - database module, and article module (something that stores articles for blog), all with some configuration parameters.

So - article module depends on storage, And having two instances of article module and database module (with different parameters) allows us to host two different blogs in two different databases.

I tried to implement this creating new namespaces for each initialized module on-the-fly, and defining functions in this namespaces with partially applied parameters. But this approach is some sort of hacking, i think.

What is right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'module' is a noun, as in the '[Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)' by Steve Yegge.

Stick to non side-effecting or pure functions of their parameters (verbs) as much as possible except at the topmost levels of your abstractions.  You can organize those functions however you like.  At the topmost levels you will have some application state, there are many approaches to manage that, but the one I use the most is to hide these top-level services under a clojure protocol, then implement it in a clojure record (which may hold references to database connections or some-such).

This approach maximizes flexibility and prevents you from writing yourself into a corner.  It's analagous to java's dependency injection.  Stuart Sierra did a good talk recently on these topics at Clojure/West 2013, but the video is not yet available.

Note the difference from your approach.  You need to separate the management and resolution of objects from their lifecycles. Tying them to namespaces is quick for access, but it means any functions you write as clients that use that code are now accessing global state.  With protocols, you can separate the implementation detail of global state from the interface of access.

If you need a motivating example of why this is useful, consider, how would you intercept all access to a service that's globally accessible?  Well, you would push the full implementation down and make the entry point a wrapper function, instead of pushing the relevant details closer to the client code.  What if you wanted some behavior for some clients of the code and not others?  Now you're stuck.  This is just anticipating making those inevitable trade-offs preemptively and making your life easier.

Comment: _Stuart Sierra did a good talk recently on these topics at Clojure/West 2013, but the video is not yet available._ - Any updates?